# Jquery Validation sample for form validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Im completely new in Jquery and since I dont know how to validate form fields using jquery, could someone please show me a sample jquery validation?

This is the code i am trying to convert to jquery.

```
var x=document.forms["form1"]["org_id_no"].value;

if (x==null || x=="")
{
    alert("Must have an organisation id number");
    return false;
}
```

How do I code it in jquery?

Comment: add your form html code and mention what all validations must be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    if($('form#login :input#logInUsername').val()=="")
    { 
       alert("Must have an organisation id number"); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming org_id_no is id of a element. This below will be corresponding jQuery code

```
var x = $('#org_id_no').val();
if(($.trim(x)).length == 0){
alert("Must have an organisation id number"); return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
   $('YoursubmitbuttonID').live("click",function(){
             validateForm();     
                });
 });


    function validateForm()
    {
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["org_id_no"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("Must have an organisation id number");
      return false;
      }
    }
</script >
```

Do not forget to include `.js` file.

Comment: I would recommend calling your form validation script on submit (so that way your form will be validated even if they submit by pressing on the return key). I would also return the results of the `validateForm` from the callback so it'll stop the submission of the form if it doesn't validate.